# How do you get the rotation (or transform) of WMR motion controllers

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-mixed-reality

Is there a way to access the rotation of a controller using WMRToolkit? I know about solvers, but they seem to focus on using position. For reference, the idea is simply to set the rotation of another gameobject to be the same as the rotation of the controller, which seems like it should be a simple task.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document shows how to use Unity API to get the position and rotation of a motion controller：[Getting a hand or motion controller's pose](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/mixed-reality/gestures-and-motion-controllers-in-unity#getting-a-hand-or-motion-controllers-pose)

Besides, there is a new XR input mapping system in Unity 2019.1, if you are using unity of 2019.1 or later, you can try the following code:

```
bool TryGetCenterEyeFeature(out Quaternion rotation)
{
    InputDevice device = InputDevices.GetDeviceAtXRNode(XRNode.RightHand);
    if (device.isValid)
    {
        if (device.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.deviceRotation, out rotation))
            return true;
    }
    rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Worked! cant believe i missed that part of the doc. Thanks.